# Toggle Class on Div when Button has Class .active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, toggle

I have a checkbox button that toggles to .active `<div class="btn thisBtn active">`:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn thisBtn">
    <input type="checkbox"> This
  </label>
  <label class="btn thatBtn">
    <input type="checkbox"> That
  </label>
</div>
```

And I would like that active state to trigger a class toggle on `<div class="thisDiv hidden">`

```
$( function() {
  if ( $( ".thisBtn" ).is( ".active" ) ) {
      $( ".thisDiv" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
      $( ".thisDiv" ).addClass( "show" );
  } else {
      $( ".thisDiv" ).removeClass( "show" );
      $( ".thisDiv" ).addClass( "hidden" );
  }
});
```

Comment: `I have a radio button`, Where is it? All I see is checkbox.

Comment: I don't see any code adding the `active` to anything. Which is kind of a problem, as that's where you want to do this.

Comment: @Satpal typo.. it's a checkbox button

Comment: @T.J.Crowder bootstrap3 adds the .active class to the checkboxBtn on.click.. Any suggestions for getting this to work?

Comment: @Satpal any suggestions for getting this to work?

Comment: @StackThis: Might have been worth mentioning Bootstrap somewhere in your question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your snippet to listen to checkbox change instead of removing/adding classes to perform less jQuery operations.

```
 $("#checkbox").change(function() {
       $("#checkbox-show").toggle(); 
    });
```

The HTML markup would be something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn thisBtn">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> This
  </label>
  <label class="btn thatBtn">
    <input type="checkbox"> That
  </label>
</div>

<div id="checkbox-show" style="display:none;">On checkbox select</div>
```

If you are displaying the form by using templating engine, you can set #checkbox-show to have display:block on load, only when #checkbox is checked. If not, just perform simple if statement to show/hide div with jQuery only once, on document ready.

Comment: this works great.. thanks.. especially with the templating engine.. why is that the case though? Have posted a specific question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452876/why-do-jquery-displayhide-effects-only-work-with-embedded-css-displaynone/23452945?noredirect=1#comment35951312_23452945