# Why do jQuery display&hide effects only work with embedded css display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I have a couple of .handlebars templates that load into a handlebars default layout, using handlebars as the view engine for node.js

The templates load into the body tag using a {{{ body }}} html escape:

```
<body>
{{{ body }}}
</body>
```

When involving divs from the templates..why do jQuery display/hide effects work this way:

```
<label class="btn">
  <input type="checkbox" id="theBtn"> theBtn
</label>

..a bunch of html..

<div class="theDiv" style="display:none;"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#theBtn").change(function() {
       $(".theDiv").slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

But this way only works if the HTML is directly written in the default layout, not from templates:

```
.hide {
display: none;
}

<label class="btn">
  <input type="checkbox" id="theBtn"> theBtn
</label>

..a bunch of html..

<div class="theDiv hide"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#theBtn").on('click', function () {
      var $when = $(".theDiv");
      $when.slideToggle();
      $(".theDiv").not($when).slideUp();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have duplicated `id` for the `input` elements. Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="theBtn" />
```

After that, you need to target only the previous sibling `.theDiv` of parent label of your clicked `input`, currently you've targeted all the `.div`, so you can use:

```
var $when = $(this).parent().prev();
```

instead of:

```
var $when = $(".theDiv");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLMAD/1/)**

Comment: theBtn is the only #theBtn id in the whole scope.. would like to use locative methods because there will be multiple .theDiv elements.. but there is a bunch of html in between #theBtn and .theDiv, for formatting and such.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></kbd>
*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change","#theBtn",function () {
        var $when = $(".theDiv");
        $when.slideToggle();
        $(".theDiv").not($when).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...!!

Comment: well, yeh, but this doesn't work within handelbars templates.. thanks for the answer though

Comment: Why don't you create a Fiddle using handlebars template.. @StackThis see the updated answer.. ***[jQuery.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)*** might be the solution to your problem..

Comment: How do you set up the Fiddle to simulate inserting a .handelbars template in a default layout? This is a server side action.. Is there a clientSide equivalent? Appreciate your thoughts on this..

Comment: all good.. would fiddle otherwise.. the problem is really with the .hide vs. style="display:none;" ... for whatever reason, the class definition of the external css only works when the html is literally in the main layout, when the html is in a template only the embedded style works.. was just wondering why..

Comment: @StackThis Making [Handlebar Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/) is possible... just show use the JSON retrieved from the server....